# ¿Es posible ejecutar la acción de un controlador desde fuera de RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quiero saber si es posible ejecutar la acción de un controlador de un servidor RoR  ( `$ rails server` )  desde un programa ruby simple fuera del servidor y en un directorio distinto, algo así como esto:

Intenté con este código:

```
$ cat programa.rb

require ‘action_controller/integration’
app = ActionController::Integration::Session.new;

app.get('controlador/accion')
```

El ejecutarlo

```
$ ruby programa.rb
```

me da este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from programa.rb:1:in `<main>'
    1: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- action_controller/integration (LoadError)
```

Comment: ¿Para qué necesitas ejecutar una acción del controlador, qué fin persigues? La mejor opción sería a través de una tarea `rake` y no un script de Ruby independiente. Si nos das mayor detalle podemos ayudar a encontrar una mejor solución.

Comment: Te explico amigo Gerry, tengo un servicio en linux que me da unos parametros y esos parametros modifican una tabla de la base de datos de la aplicación que se refrescan automaticamente via cable. la unica forma que veo es por un script independiente, igual voy a leer sobre la tarea rake, que lo que he leido hasta ahora es una proceso que hay que llamar manualmente

Comment: Una tarea _rake_ la puedes llamar desde la línea de comando con un script, de la misma forma que lo harías para ejecutar el script en _ruby_. Sin embargo, considerando que recibes información de otro servicio; ¿no sería mejor generar un _endpoint_ (API) para ese fin?

Comment: Concuerdo con gerry que la forma adecuada de llamar código de una aplicación rails es a través de un rake task. En teoría podrías hacer lo que intentas, pero cada distinto componente de rails está tan acoplado a otros componentes (existen programadores que odian esto de rails y han creado sus propios proyectos como hanami o trailblazer), aparte de las configuraciones que tendrías que cargar... al final es reinventar la rueda de algo que puedes hacer perfectamente con un rake task.

Comment: okey. me puede dar un enlace que me oriente como hacer un endpoint?

Comment: LISTO; Estos días lo invertí para aprender sobre tareas en rails y como ejecutarlo con un shell al iniciar la máquina, el truco para que se ejecute la tarea de rails es leer rvm como una función (source /$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm)  y cambiar al perfil de usuario que trabaja con ruby.